# How can we scroll the table view at the same time the keyboard is open?

Tags: objective-c, swift, scroll, keyboard

I want to have control of the keyboard that is open and be able to scroll the table view at the same time. I have to close the keyboard to scroll the table view now.

Comment: are you using a text field in table view cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you register notification in viewDidLoad and unregister notification in your viewWillDisappear

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
           name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
         object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
    addObserver:self
       selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
           name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
         object:nil];
```

simply adjust the contentInset of the tableview by the height of the keyboard, and then scroll the cell to the bottom:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    self.myTableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.myTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;


}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^(void) 
    {
        self.myTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        self.myTableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic `ViewController` to handle the condition when there is a view need to show up during the keyboard is showing up. What you have to do is to inherit the `BaseInputController` and `override` the `showAnimation` and `hideAnimation`. Present your new controller to test it!

```
class BaseInputController: UIViewController, BaseInputProtocol {

    private var blur: UIVisualEffectView!

    init(){
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve
        modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    deinit{
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setUI()
        setNotification()

    }

    private func setUI(){

        blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark))
        blur.alpha = 0
        view.addSubview(blur)
        let tap1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(BaseInputController.cancelHandle))
        blur.addGestureRecognizer(tap1)
        blur.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalTo(view)
        }

    }

    @objc private func cancelHandle(){
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(
            false,
            completion: nil
        )
    }

    private func setNotification(){
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(BaseInputController.keyBoardWillShow(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(BaseInputController.keyBoardWillHide(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func keyBoardWillShow(note:NSNotification){

        guard let userInfo = note.userInfo,
            height = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue().size.height,
            duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
            else{ return }

        UIView.animateWithDuration(
            duration.doubleValue,
            delay: 0,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(duration.integerValue) << 16),
            animations: {
                self.blur.alpha = 1
                self.showAnimation(height)
            },
            completion: nil
        )

    }

    func showAnimation(height: CGFloat){

    }

    func keyBoardWillHide(note:NSNotification){

        guard let userInfo = note.userInfo,
            duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
            else{ return }

        UIView.animateWithDuration(
            duration.doubleValue,
            delay: 0,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(duration.integerValue) << 16),
            animations: {
                self.blur.alpha = 0
                self.hideAnimation()
            },
            completion: {
                if $0 { self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) }
            }
        )

    }

    func hideAnimation(){

    }

    func hideInput(){

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Move the table view according to the keyboard.

```
CGPoint pointInTable = [textView.superview convertPoint:textView.frame.origin toView:self.tblEditTask];
CGPoint contentOffset = self.tblEditTask.contentOffset;

contentOffset.y = (pointInTable.y - textView.inputAccessoryView.frame.size.height);

NSLog(@"contentOffset is: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(contentOffset));

[self.tblEditTask setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:YES];
```